# Is it possible to replicate kafka topics without alias prefix with MirrorMaker2

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I'm trying to set up replication between 2 clusters but don't want want the topic names to be changed. for example if i have a topic called "some_topic" it is automatically replicated to "cluster1.some_topic", I'm pretty sure this can be done but haven't found the correct config to change this

My current config "mirrormaker2.properties"

```
# Sample MirrorMaker 2.0 top-level configuration file
# Run with ./bin/connect-mirror-maker.sh connect-mirror-maker.properties 

# specify any number of cluster aliases
clusters = cluster1, cluster2

# connection information for each cluster
cluster1.bootstrap.servers = host1:9092,host2:9092,host3:9092
cluster2.bootstrap.servers = rep_host1:9092,rep_host2:9092,rep_host3:9092

# enable and configure individual replication flows
cluster1->cluster2.enabled = true
cluster1->cluster2.topics = sometopic.*

# customize as needed
# replication.policy.separator = _
# sync.topic.acls.enabled = false
# emit.heartbeats.interval.seconds = 5
```

for reference:

- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-382%3A+MirrorMaker+2.0#KIP-382:MirrorMaker2.0-RunningastandaloneMirrorMakerconnector
- https://kafka.apache.org/24/javadoc/index.html?constant-values.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer above is inappropriate.

In Mirror Maker 2.0, if you want to keep the topic unmodified, you have to implement ReplicationPolicy.

You can refer to DefaultReplicationPolicy.class, and then override `formatRemoteTopic()`, after that you have to remove `sourceClusterAlias + separator`. In the end, configure `replication.policy.class` in the `mm2.properties`

I defined `MigrationReplicationPolicy.class`

```
replication.policy.class = org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MigrationReplicationPolicy
```

You should see `MirrorClientConfig,class`, I know that you will understand

Comment: Can you post a link to the custom `MigrationReplicationPolicy.class` you created ?

Answer (score 16):

Starting with Kafka 3.0.0, it is sufficient to set

```
replication.policy.class=org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.IdentityReplicationPolicy
```

Also, the PrefixlessReplicationPolicy in marcin-wieloch's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60619233/12008693 no longer works with 3.0.0 (NullPointerException).

Comment: When I use this policy, would it overwrite the data in the Target topic? Given that Target topic already exists and has data.

Answer (score 14):

To 'disable' topic prefixes **and to have topic properties mirrored properly** at the same time, I had to provide a customized replication policy which also overrides the `topicSource` method. Otherwise non-default topic properties (e.g., `"cleanup.policy=compact"`) have not been mirrored, even after restarting mirror maker.

Here is the complete procedure that worked for me:

1. Compile and package the following customized replication policy into a .jar file (full source code can be found [here](https://github.com/mawileo/mm2-prefixless-policy/blob/feature/prefixless/src/main/java/ch/mawileo/kafka/mm2/PrefixlessReplicationPolicy.java)):

```
public class PrefixlessReplicationPolicy extends DefaultReplicationPolicy {

  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PrefixlessReplicationPolicy.class);

  private String sourceClusterAlias;

  @Override
  public void configure(Map<String, ?> props) {
    super.configure(props);
    sourceClusterAlias = (String) props.get(MirrorConnectorConfig.SOURCE_CLUSTER_ALIAS);
    if (sourceClusterAlias == null) {
      String logMessage = String.format("Property %s not found", MirrorConnectorConfig.SOURCE_CLUSTER_ALIAS);
      log.error(logMessage);
      throw new RuntimeException(logMessage);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public String formatRemoteTopic(String sourceClusterAlias, String topic) {
    return topic;
  }

  @Override
  public String topicSource(String topic) {
    return topic == null ? null : sourceClusterAlias;
  }

  @Override
  public String upstreamTopic(String topic) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

2. Copy the .jar into the `${KAFKA_HOME/libs` directory
3. Configure Mirror Maker 2 to use that replication policy by setting the `replication.policy.class` property in `${KAFKA_HOME}/config/mm2.properties`:

```
  replication.policy.class=ch.mawileo.kafka.mm2.PrefixlessReplicationPolicy
```

Comment: This is a pretty good answer for me but I got one question : why didn't you just change the method formatRemoteTopic and call `super` on other method ? (worked on my side)

Comment: Hi @Naremy, by 'other method' do you mean `topicSource` and `upstreamTopic`? 

When I left those methods unchanged then mirroring of topics' properties did not work. In my Kafka setup for example topics by default are not compacted; and when I created a topic which I wanted to be compacted (so I set the `"cleanup.policy=compact"` property for that topic) the mirrored topic on the downstream side still had the default properties (i.e., no compaction).

Does mirroring of topic properties work with your solution?

Comment: In the future it looks like this will not be necessary. As of July 2021 a IdentityReplicationPolicy has been added to MirrorMaker2. It does not appear to be part of a release yet. https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/mirror-client/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/mirror/IdentityReplicationPolicy.java

Answer (score 10):

I was able to remove the prefix using this setup:

```
"replication.policy.separator": ""
"source.cluster.alias": "",
"target.cluster.alias": "",
```

If the alias setting is necessary in your case, I understand you should use other replicationPolicy class. By default is using DefaultReplicationPolicy class (https://kafka.apache.org/24/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/mirror/DefaultReplicationPolicy.html)

Answer (score 4):

Managed to push replication with Kafka ConfluentINC Connector image release 5.4.2
Properties are:

```cs
connector.class=org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector
target.cluster.alias= 
replication.factor=3
tasks.max=3
topics=.*
source.cluster.alias= 
target.cluster.bootstrap.servers=<broker1>,<broker2>,<broker3>
replication.policy.separator= 
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
source.cluster.bootstrap.servers=<broker1>,<broker2>,<broker3>
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
```

1) Leave space after the 3 parameters: source.cluster.alias, replication.policy.separator, target.cluster.alias.

2) Set this mirror connector on the TARGET Kafka, NOT on the source (performs pull only)

In addition yo  can use Conductor or Kafka Connector UI landoop image - landoop/kafka-connect-ui

This is still in a testing scenario, but it looks promising.

Answer (score 3):

I'm trying to set up replication between 2 clusters, but need the same topic name in both the cluster without giving an alias for the in the connect-mirror-maker.properties.

By default, replicated topics are renamed based on source cluster aliases.

```
    Source --> Target
    topic-1 --> source.topic-1
```

You can avoid topics being renamed by setting the following properties to blank under your connector properties file. By default, replication.policy.separator property is a period, then by setting it to blank along with the source.cluster.alias, the target topic will have the same name as the source topic.

```
replication.policy.separator=
source.cluster.alias=
target.cluster.alias=
```

---