# Avoid cluster prefix on topics while on active active configuration on Kafka MirrorMaker 2

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I need to use MirrorMaker 2 to replicate information in an active active setup, but I also need it not to change the topic names by adding the cluster name as prefix like it usually does.

I was able to supress the prefix by modifying the replication.policy.separator and source and target aliases (sourcetarget.cluster.alias). But that results in an infinite loop where messages get replicated indefinetly. Is there any way to avoid this while at the same time having no prefixes whatsoever?

Essentially what I'm looking for is a specific replication policy, or configuration that uses something different than the prefix to avoid the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to remove the prefix.

But I don't recommend doing this. Do you have more information about why this is a requirement?

You can use the replication policy. Take a look at this question.

[Is it possible to replicate kafka topics without alias prefix with MirrorMaker2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59390555/is-it-possible-to-replicate-kafka-topics-without-alias-prefix-with-mirrormaker2)

Comment: Thank you. I noticed that I didn't mention that in my original question. But I added now that I tried changing the properties file I feed to connect-mirror-maker.sh and managed to supress the prefixes but since its an active-active configuration that results in an infinite loop. What I'm looking for is a specific replication policy, or configuration that uses metadata instead of a prefix to avoid the infinite loop.

This is needed to preserve transparency between different systems while having the information replicated.